# Angular2 how to display an array of numbers

Tags: html, angular

Whats is the most elegant solution in angular2 for displaying an html table of z numbers in x rows and y columns?

X, Y and Z are numbers not necessarily collections. Also the table should contain numbers 1 to z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this : **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9ZblVrohDyl1RpnXjL6v?p=preview)**

Component

```
rows : any[];
cols : any[];

constructor() { 
  this.rows = Array(50).fill('');
  this.cols = Array(10).fill('');
}
```

Template :

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let rowId = index">
    <td *ngFor="let col of cols; let colId = index">{{rowId + colId*10+1}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: how is this going to work if rows and cols are numbers. I have a table of 500 numbers and I wish to display a 10 by 50 table

Comment: @Shakur By doing as the edit above.

Comment: And how do we print 1 to 500 :) something so simple doesn't seem intuitive at all to me with angular2

Comment: @Shakur By adding indexes ! (Like on the edit)